# Grow several citronella geranium plants from one plant?

Tags: houseplants, containers, propagation, mosquito

I just bought a small potted citronella geranium plant at Home Depot, something like this:
[image]

Is it possible to use this *one* plant to grow several pots of citronella geranium plants?

Comment: I think yes, if it is like other geranium (Pelargonium), Just you need a larger plant (and larger branches).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi agreed. Absolutely possible, but this plant is too small.

Answer (score 1):

Your plant is basically a pelargonium (colloquially called geraniums) with a lot of lemony scent. So the propagation process is the same as for other geraniums: make cuttings from new growth, dip the ends in rooting hormone (optional) and stick them in soil.

From experience, the scented types are a bit fussier to propagate than the decorative P. grandiflorum hybrids that were bred for exuberant flowers and more vigorous growth. But it’s absolutely doable with them as well. You may need a bit more patience as the slower-growing scented geraniums push fewer new branches than the P. grandiflorums, giving you less material to work with.